# I have multiple JMSlisteners where am using @JMSListener annotation with queue as destination. Observing the loss of events in our listeners

Tags: mq

The volume of our application is too huge i.e around 500million per day. We are observing some loss of events. Please share if anyone has observed loss of events while consuming using @JmsListener.

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons:

1. some of your messages are producing errors and they are generating rollbacks which you didn't handle carefully
2. you are not using transactions while you are having connectivity / sync / infrastructure issues
3. it can be your configuration: not using persistent messaging, caching messages on client side within driver (etc..)

Whatever it is it is NOT issue of @JmsListner annotation, but of code, driver and messaging configuration.